# spring security angularjs forbidden 403

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add spring security to angularjs application. I am following this tutorial about securing single page application with spring security:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii

The difference is that I am not using spring boot but spring mvc for this purpose. I think I added everything I need but for some reason after typing the inMemory credentials I get 403 forbidden.

Here is my spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("initTT");
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http
    .httpBasic()
  .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
   .csrf().disable();
}


 @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/app/**"); 
  }

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
      repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
      return repository;
    }
```

}

I used the authenicate() function from the tutorial and added it to my app.js file:

```
coursesApp.controller('loginController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {


      var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {
        var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
            + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
        } : {};


       console.log(headers);
        $http.get('/basic-web-app/user', {headers : headers}).success(function(data) {
          if (data.name) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
          } else {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          }
          callback && callback();
        }).error(function() {
          $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          callback && callback();
        });

      }

      authenticate();
      $scope.credentials = {};
      $scope.login = function() {
          console.log("login clicked!!!!!!!");
          authenticate($scope.credentials, function() {
            if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
              console.log("authenticated");
              $location.path("/");
              $scope.error = false;
            } else {
              console.log("not authenticated");
              $location.path("/login");
              $scope.error = true;
            }
          });
      };
    });
```

I have the UserController and 
    /user
endpoint as described in the tutorial. I am scanning the package with this

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.courses.portal.controllers"/>
```

[image]

I am also attaching a screen shot of the chrome console in order to be clear what I am doing:

web.xml file:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.courses.portal.controllers"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/build/"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.courses.portal.controllers.*.*(..))"
                                   access="ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:global-method-security>


</beans>
```

Sorry if it is a common question but I tried to find anything useful on the web before posting. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are sending the correct header. Can you get some DEBUG logs from the server for that request?

Comment: I removed some configuration from the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and now it prints out the pricniple in the console:
org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4428690f:

But the chrome developer console says 404 not found for:
http://localhost:8087/basic-web-app/user

Updated the question with the web.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml files

Comment: for sure I messed up the configuration. When I paste http://localhost:8087/basic-web-app/user in the web browser it returns 
HTTP Status 404 - /basic-web-app/WEB-INF/jsp/user.jsp

Comment: I believe the issue is in the view resolver setup because it is trying to access /basic-web-app/WEB-INF/jsp/user.jsp

Comment: Maybe you could put your whole project in github and paste a link here?

Comment: Dave, I think I found my mistake. In the controller I missed the following annotation @ResponseBody. After adding it I managed to authenticate and achieve what I wanted. Thank you very much for the wonderful tutorial and the advises you gave me! I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (you haven't really posted all the code) is that /basic-web-app is a context root, which is a servlet API construct - you need it in your client if you are making absolute paths, but it doesn't know about servlets, however Spring Security is servlet based, so it doesn't need the prefix (which I noticed you removed from the `/app/**` config for your static resources). Try removing the prefix from the security config path.

Comment: My code in the SecurityConfig is as follows:
...
    .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
....
It does not work. Again 403 forbidden. This is my code at the moment but when I posted the question I pasted the wrong configure() method. So the context root was excluded a day ago. Put the correct state. Sorry.:/

Comment: I am having trouble finding the state information that your OAuth2 `authserver` app should be sending in Step C of the authorization code grant type flow.  I am trying to create a node.js client app in place of your `ui` sample app.  Are you willing to comment on where the node.js client should look to find the state information that it needs to handle between Steps C and D of the flow?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133114/client-not-passing-authserver-credentials

Comment: @DaveSyer Does your `authserver` app require different configuration in order to serve non-spring clients, such as a node.js client?  Even a comment to this effect would GREATLY narrow the work of developing a non-spring client for your `authserver`.  If I know that 100% of the issue is in the `oauth2` **client**, then I can know to focus solely on the client.  Please comment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018644/spring-security-angularjs-forbidden-403/38020430#comment63698561_38020430

Comment: The server is basically spec-compliant out of the box with very little effort, so almost certainly your client is the place to focus.

Comment: @DaveSyer I validated with two other client apps to confirm that the problem is that the Spring OAuth2 `authserver` app is **NOT OAuth2 compliant** because it cannot authenticate non-Spring clients.  The problem might be in the filter chain in front of the token endpoint.  I created a GitHub ticket to summarize the problem, including two separate sample client apps to use for testing: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/806